# What is the logic behind these if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement, logic

I'm new to coding so I don't really understand the logic behind some of this stuff. I do understand a basic if statement. Could someone please eli5 the logic below and why it doesn't work?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("mode", help="Use encode/decode")
args = parser.parse_args()
mode = args.mode
encode = 'encode'
decode = 'decode'
```

Now for my if statements. This one works fine but I want the inverse.

```
if mode == encode or mode == decode:
   print("Mode is supported!")
```

This one works fine and figured out after some searching

```
if not (mode == encode or mode == decode):
   print("Mode isn't supported")
   exit()
```

Why is this next one not an inverse of the first one?

```
if mode != encode or mode != decode:
   print("Mode is encode or decode)
   exit()
```

**EDIT and ANSWER**
A lot of people told me to check out De Morgan's Law, which I did, and it too me a long time to really understand (I never fully understood until I made some test functions in vs code). I think I have it figured out now

```
    if mode == encode or mode == decode:
       print("Mode isn't encode or decode")
mode = encode True or false = True
mode = decode False or True = True
mode = test False or False = False
```

So this next one is NOT correct.

```
    if mode != encode or mode != decode:
       print("Mode isn't encode or decode")
       exit()
mode = encode False or True = True
mode = decode False or True = True
mode = test True or True = False
```

The next one is correct.

```
     if not (mode == encode or mode == decode):
       print("Mode isn't encode or decode")
       exit()
mode = encode (True or False) = True # not(True) = False
mode = decode (False or True) = True # not(True) = False
mode = test (False or False) = False # not(False) = True
```

`if not (mode == encode or mode == decode):`
seems  like the true inverse of
`if mode == encode or mode == decode:`

And I believe with my new knowledge that this next one should work.

```
    if mode != encode and mode != decode:
       print("Mode isn't encode or decode")
       exit()
mode = encode False and True = False
mode = decode True and False = False
mode = test True and True = True
```

I know my answer to myself was kind of long winded but I hope I spelled this out in a way that is able to help other code noobs.

Comment: Check out [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). `mode != encode and mode != decode` would be equivalent to the second one.

Comment: What does your code do?  Why does it not work?

Comment: @chepner I will check that out. Thank you.

Comment: @iguananaut right now it doesn't really do anything. I'm just practicing simple things and learning argparse arguments. so to run the script you would use script.py <mode>. I want mode to either be encode or decode. I have variables encode = 'encode' and vise versa. I wanted to error if mode does not equal encode or decode and at first I expected the 3rd option to work how I intended

Comment: A complication in this question is that we don't know what's in these variables. Particularly `encode` or `decode`. If both of these variables are the same value, the `if`'s work differently. Can you initialize the `encode` and `decode` or use string (or integer) literals for those?

Comment: @tdelaney, I've edited the question to hopefully clear everything up. Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: In `if mode != encode or mode != decode:` - one of these two tests is always true. If mode is "decode" then `mode != encode` is True and the evaluation stops. If mode is "encode" then `mode != decode` is True. If mode is "whatever", that first `mode != encode` is True. A better way is to test for inclusion: `if mode in (encode, decode)` or if mode not in (encode, decode)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are new to Python, I suggest you this way:
Think all possible scenario that you will have:

```
1) mode = "encode"
2) mode = "decode"
3) mode = "yolol" (something that not in both cases, this can represent all cases that not equal to encode or decode)
```

For the first:
`mode == encode or mode == decode:`
Both case one and case two will pass, since mode is either two; and case three not pass
For the second:
`not (mode == encode or mode == decode)`
Both case one and case two will not pass while case three will, since you are just basically flip the first scenario
For the third:
`if mode != encode or mode != decode:`. Now all three will pass, since encode is True when mode != decode (also means encode != decode, which is True), decode != mode is also True, yolo != True.
You might want to check up De Morgan's law for more about boolean expression

Comment: I've spent about the last 2 hours trying to understand De Morgan's Law. So hopefully I have a better understanding if you could confirm what I'm thinking. It's a little long so I have it in the next comment. The first one is pretty easy for me to understand so I only have 2 and 3 written out.

Comment: `if not (mode == encode or mode == decode):`
I believe now that this one actually works by resolving the parenth first. For example mode == encode we will have True or False which is True for the whole parenth. so then, if not True = False. mode == test the parenth is false or false and if not False we get true.

using the same kind of logic I think the reason why the 3rd one doesn't work.

`if mode != encode or mode != decode:`
mode = encode (false or true) which is true
mode = test (true or true) which is true

Comment: So we could do `if mode != encode and mode != decode:`
Because if mode = encode then we would get True and False which is false. and mode = test we would get False and False which is True?

Comment: First, yes, always resolving the parenth first. Second, encode are True in the bracket, since it is the OR expression and it only need one to pass. test, however cannot pass, since they are not equal to encode and not equal to decode. Remember the not, so the result is then flipped. The third case you got a bit wrong, as False and False is also False. So the third case is different than other two because all input case with return False regardless

Answer (score 1):

According to De Morgan's law
`'not(A or B)' is equals to 'not(A) and not(B)'`

By applying this to your expression, `'not (mode == encode or mode == decode)'` is equals to `'not(mode == encode) and not(mode == decode)'` is equals to `'mode != encode and mode != decode'`

Comment: Thank you. I believe I have it figured out now. I looked at de Morgan's Law for about 3 hours and also made some tests in vs code. I responded with my new ideas to Long's post. and will update my post

Answer (score 0):

Basically, if we have a variable that is the mode tou want to set, wich is `mode_to_be_used` , and this variable contains a `string` either being `"decode"` or `"encode"`, you can test if this variable contains the data `"encode"` by doing :

```
mode_to_be_used = "encode"
if mode_to_be_used == "encode" :
  print("The mode here was : ", mode_to_be_used )
```

It will print the mode only if `mode_to_be_used` 's value is `"encode"`

So, doing :

```
mode_to_be_used = "decode"
if mode_to_be_used == "encode" :
  print("The mode here was : ", mode_to_be_used )
```

Won't print anything on your screen.

By extension, doing :

```
mode_to_be_used = "encode"
if mode_to_set  == "encode" or mode_to_set  == "encode" :
  print("The mode here was : ", mode_to_be_used )
```

Will print the value that was inside `mode_to_be_used` if it contained `"encode"` **or** `"decode"`. But it won't if it contained `"foo"` for example.

To care for that, you can do :

```
mode_to_be_used = "test"

if mode_to_set  == "encode" or mode_to_set  == "encode" :
  print("The mode here was : ", mode_to_be_used )
  if mode_to_set  == "encode":
    print("now doing the encoding")
  if mode_to_set  == "decode":
    print("now doing the decoding")

else :
  print("This value is not expected for mode_to_set :", mode_to_set  )
```

Comment: As this question is quite low on programation level and the author states himself that he is new to coding, i assumed a theoretical use of his code based on the variables names, and changed the structure compared to the question (with strings) as if he doesn't already understands this case, the won't understand with a comparison of two variables : ``mode`` ``decode`` / ``encode`` : these two can be anything : maybe a bool ? maybe a string ? maybe a more complex object or a function ?